# How to update WPF UI from override method

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to update a WPF UI from the ViewModel.

The ViewModel:

```
ConcreteObserver : Observer<Mouse>, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

        private string _key;

        public DelegateCommand TestDelegateCommand { get; set; }

        public string Key
        {
            get { return _key; }
            set { _key = value;
                 OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Key)); 
               }
        }


        public ConcreteObserver ()
        {
            TestDelegateCommand = new DelegateCommand(UpdateGui);
        }

        private void UpdateGui()
        {
            Key = "Test refresh";
        }

        public override void Update(TestObject subject)
        {
            Key = "Test Update";

            if (subject is TestObject)
            {
                subject.MouseAction += OnMouse;
                subject.Start();

            }
        }

        private void OnMouse(object sender, RowMouseDataEventArgs e)
        {
            Key += "1";
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

The View:

```
 <UserControl.DataContext>
        <local:ConcreteObserver />
    </UserControl.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock
            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
            VerticalAlignment="Center"
            Text="{Binding Key, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
        <Button
            VerticalAlignment="Top"
            HorizontalAlignment="Right"
            Content="Click"
            Command="{Binding TestDelegateCommand}" />
    </Grid>
```

I have an event that is triggered when I click the mouse and the event works fine.

The problem that the UI is not updated if the `Key` is changed within the `Update` method and nothing is 
displayed on the GUI if the `Key` property changes.

I set a breakpoint and watched the change from the `Key` property and everything works fine but the GUI doesn't recognize the change.

I tested it with a button, the changes are shown when I click on the button.

**EDIT**:
Here where i call the `Update` Method (Observer pattern):

```
  public void NotifyObservers(T hookSubject)
    {
        if (hookSubject == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException($"{nameof(hookSubject)}             cannot be null.");
            }

            foreach (var hookObserver in _hooksObservers)
            {
                hookObserver.UpdateHook(hookSubject);
            }
        }
```

And here where i call the `NotifyObservers` (In a MouseHook class)

```
public void NotifyObservers()
        {
            NotifyObservers(this);
        }
```

Can someone explain to me why.

Comment: Is the update method called from the same UI thread or some other thread?

Comment: From the UI thread

Comment: Can u debug and check when key value is changed in update method, propertychanged event has any handler(listener)?

Comment: I did it and the `Key` value changes in the `Update` method

Comment: I mean this line   PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));

Comment: Why shouldn't that work? As I mentioned, it worked with the button, which means that the event works fine

Comment: Can u show how and where u have called the update method

Comment: The update method is called elsewhere in the program. but as even OnMouse is always triggered when I click the mouse

Comment: When mouse clicks happens events are raised on UI thread and update happens on the same thread. So it works always. If u can provide where it called it might  be helpful. I still believe update method is not called from UI thread. That can be one cause, resulted in exception when propertychange event is raised. Exception is hidden. Check the debug trace if u can find out any exception occured while binding is updated

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're calling `Update` on the wrong object

Comment: Do not repost the same question. If you are having trouble getting your original question answered, [edit the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61689171/edit) to address problems that may exist with it. Make sure your question includes a good [mcve], a clear explanation of what you tried, why that didn't work, and what _specifically_ you need help with. See also [ask] for advice about how to present your question in a clear, answerable way.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably calling `Update` on the wrong object. You're instantiating an object inside XAML (`<local:ConcreteObserver />`) so I assume that you don't hold a reference to it somewhere else, which means you're probably changing the wrong `Key`.

It's hard to test for sure without a proper example (minimal yet complete code of how the `Update` method is being called)